# let :${\displaystyle F_{1}=F_{2}=1,\forall n>2:F_{n}=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}}$ then :

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

let :${\displaystyle F_{1}=F_{2}=1,\forall n>2:F_{n}=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}}$

then :

$$\frac{F_{100}}{F_{99}}+\frac{F_{99}}{F_{100}}=?$$

my try :

$1=\frac{F_{n-1}}{F_{n}}+\frac{F_{n-2}}{F_{n}}!!!!$

Continuation!!!

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}=\varphi = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n} + \frac{F_n}{F_{n+1}} \approx \varphi + \frac{1}{\varphi} = \sqrt{5}
$$
Indeed,
$$
\frac{F_{100}}{F_{99}}+\frac{F_{99}}{F_{100}} - \sqrt{5} \approx -5.8  \times 10^{-42}
$$